# Retrieve a list of registered routes

Tags: routes, castle-monorail

I am trying to throw together a documentation site for a set of web services built with monorail and am wondering if there is a way to get a list of routes registered in RoutingModuleEx.Engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any direct way to do that. The simplest way would be duplicating the added routes to a local list, which you can manage as you please. The other way would be accessing `RoutingModuleEx.Engine`'s private list of routes via reflection (collections are named `rules` and `name2Rule`, [see source](https://github.com/castleproject/Castle.MonoRail/blob/master/src/Castle.MonoRail.Framework/Routing/BaseRoutingRuleContainer.cs#L29))